# expected identifier or '(' before '&' token

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am building a piece of code that implements the mersenne twister random unsigned long generator to simulate a slot machine. When I declare my variables in my main, I get this error code:
    error: expected identifier or '(' before '&' token.

```
int main()
{
    int window1 = 0, window2 = 0, window3 = 0;
    unsigned long &random1, &random2, &random3; /* error code on this line */
    ...
    mersenneTwister(&random1, &random2, &random3); /* calls a subroutine named mersenneTwister */
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

The subroutine runs fine; I tested it by running it on its own, and the only error is that one declaration line.

Comment: are you trying to declare pointers? Using `'&'` in that context makes no sense

Comment: what kind of variable is &random1, this is not valid name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the & operator in a declaration.  Change to:

```
    unsigned long random1, random2, random3; /* error code on this line */
```

The `&` operator is used in the call to your function to provide pointers to those variables, presumably for your `MersenneTwister` function to fill in.  The variables themselves are ordinary unsigned long objects.